# RStudio - Change number of spaces in a tab

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

I spent at least an hour trying to figure out how to change the number of spaces RStudio uses for a tab. To me using only 2 makes it extremely difficult to read the code. So after finally figuring it out, I decided to post this to save others the headache.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've seen this question asked many times with various round about and strange answers but it turns out the answer is simple.

First go to "Tools">"Global Options"> on the side bar select "Code" and change "Tab Width"

[image]

THEN next is the step everyone is missing. The option above will be overwritten if you've already started the file. So next go to "Tools">"Project Options"> on the side bar select "Code Editing" and change "Tab Width" again. I'm not actually for sure the first step was needed but it may be because that's what I did.

[image]

Finally, you simply delete all the code and paste it, and it magically has the new number of spaces! Took me a long time to figure that out and was unable to find anything with such an easy solution, so I wrote this.